# How to handle JWT refreshing on server side (Next.js or any other)

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, refresh-token

I have two cookies being stored: JWT and refresh token, both are `httponly; path=/`, so they are send on all requests, including the API (which doesn't use Bearer, but instead reads the JWT directly from the cookies).

The implementation is as usual, the JWT is short lived, and the refresh token is used to get a new one. The refresh token is rotating and after used is invalidated.

On the client, refreshing the token is no issue. When a 401 is returned by the API a call is made to `/auth/refresh-token` and the request is retried.

On the server however, (e.g. on `getServerSideProps`) it seems to be quite difficult to refresh the JWT. What I have attempted is to create a custom server and a middleware that checks when a JWT is expired and attempts to refresh it.

I can think of two issues with that, first is that the custom server is called on every resource, that includes all json, js, static files, etc... that Next.js serves. When two requests are made with the same tokens (I can handle this when making API calls, but Next.js also sends requests to the server and I cannot control those):

```
1. Two requests with expired JWT are sent to the server
2. The back-end receives the requests and on both determines it needs to refresh the token
3. Eventually one of the requests will complete, invalidating the refresh-token
4. The other request now has an invalidated refresh token and cannot get a new JWT
```

Second issue, what if the user doesn't receive the response, scenario:

```
1. A request with an expired JWT is sent
2. The back-end refreshes it and sets the new cookies
3. The back-end then has to read lots of data from a database which takes a few seconds
4. User closes the page before receiving the response
5. At this point the user has an invalidated refresh token and an expired JWT because the response with the new cookies was never received
```

How are these cases usually handled? It seems like it would be a common issue with rotating refresh tokens, but I couldn't find anything useful on this online.

Comment: _"On the server however, (e.g. on getServerSideProps) it seems to be quite difficult to refresh the JWT"_ - Can you elaborate on why it's difficult to do so in `getServerSideProps`? You have access to the cookies in `getServerSideProps` too.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this practice.

- Save refresh token in the http-only cookie
- No need to save JWT in the cookie for better security and keep it in the response of refresh token as well as login endpoint.
- Save JWT expiry in a normal cookie

Call refresh token endpoint to get new JWT when expiry token is not present or getting 401 error.

In getServerSideProps also you can call the refresh token endpoint always as you don't need to persist JWT anywhere.

You may need to get the cookie from `req.headers.cookie` and pass it in the header when you are calling the refresh token endpoint from the server.

```
//inside getServerSideProps

const browserCookie = req.headers.cookie;
const refreshJWTTokenResponse: any = await refreshJWTToken(browserCookie);


//service call

export async function refreshJWTToken(refreshTokenCookie: any): Promise<{}> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Cookie",`${refreshTokenCookie}`);
    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: headers,
        credentials:'include',

      };
    ... 
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean with the second point? Where should the JWT be saved? It somehow needs to be sent to the APIs

Comment: JWT can be saved in a variable or global store. So you can pass it to the API from the store. The only problem is when the user refreshes the page JWT variable becomes reset. So you can call the refresh token endpoint to generate a new JWT when the page load and save the new JWT into the store.